# Using Ada CE, making an indeterminate array type's instance with actual range values visible (globally) in package to procs within the package

Tags: arrays, ada

I wanted to create an array, dynamic, where I would set the range/size dynamically from user input. I settled on just passing the array as a variable to the unit getting the user input for array size. Works fine; I was hesitant as I had not passed an array as parameter, but works fine.

Comment: This question would have been better as per SO guidelines for the author to have shown actual source code with actual gotcha, then perhaps an attempted work-around alternative source code with a different gotcha.  So far the [ada] tag isn't getting strict enforcement from the SO gods on this like some other tags do, where it is commonplace to downvote 3 times then delete so-called “poorly-worded questions” even if the tag-community itself loves the content of the question.

Comment: OK, so actual source code is what I am asking about. There is no work around, or gotcha. It’s a question on scope and visibility with Ada within a package across multiple procs and functions in the package.

Comment: You are missing the point resistantly.  SO considers prose questions that in effect say “hey write my code for me from scratch” to be disdained.  You should at least make a half-hearted attempt at writing the source code yourself so that others may critique it instead of asking people to write your source code from scratch.  Indeed, Niklas below likewise said in regard to your lack of source code “I'm not sure if I understand your need correctly”.  Example source code from you would have clarified your question to the point that it would be unlikely for Niklas needing to write that clause.

Comment: My package specification file *,ads and body *,ada are too long to paste in this little box. Can I email it to you, or post it an iCloud folder shared with you?

Comment: I wouldn’t have closed this. I think you can only do this using an access-to-indefinite-array; "set[ting] its actual range bounds" would be done using `new` in the initialization procedure.  Whether you put the access object in the public or private part of the spec obviously depends on where you need it to be visible from. Private would be better!

Comment: If your question is reopened, please prepare a small, [mre] that illustrates your use-case and shows your revised approach; [edit] your question to include it. Also consider a suitable one of the `Ada.Containers`, which typically hide some of the complexity of @SimonWright's suggestion.

Comment: I went with passing the array as a parameter and it works just find. I was a little hesitant in trying, but just following. the documentation for Ada language worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your need correctly, but does something like this satisfy? Using Positive as an example of the array-index type, and Float as an example of the array-element type.

Somewhere a declaration of the unconstrained array type:

```
type Arr_Type is array (Positive range <>) of Float;
```

and in the package body:

```
package body Pkg is
   Arr : Arr_Type (15 .. 77);
   ...
   ... Rest of package body, including its subprograms etc.
   ... All can see and use the Arr directly.
   ...
end Pkg;
```

If this is not what you are looking for, perhaps your problem is that the index range (here 15 .. 77) is not statically constant, but is computed at run-time? Perhaps the range even changes from time to time within the execution of the program?